# Xamarin or Xamarion.Forms for Windows, Mac, iOS and Android app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

We are developing a slack like chat app using Xamarin. The platforms we are targeting are - iOS, Android, Windows, and Mac.
Which is the recommended Xamarin flavor we should use?

1. Xamarin Forms for iOS & Android and WPF for Windows & Xamarin.Mac for the Mac app?
2. Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Mac and WPF for windows?

We would prefer 1 since it helps us share UI code. But unsure if the PCL project of shared code will work with Mac app?

Comment: No one can answer you whether it is better to use a single UI or not as there is no objective criteria for that, depends on the project and even developer. So this question will be probably closed as 'opinion based'. However, you should note that Xamarin.Forms have Mac support in beta, as it seems to be your biggest issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since the PCL will limit your framework capability to a limited subset that is running on the platforms you chose when you create it, it will most likely not be a limiting factor to be reused on desktop environments.

The difference between the Xamarin.X and Xamarin.Forms is more like an additional toolkit support for defining UI features.

Answer (score 0):

So based @Ivan's information that Xamarin forms support for Mac is on its way, it makes sense I use Xamarin.Forms for all.

Comment: You should notice that Xamarin Forms for WPF is also coming.

Comment: @LexLi Any official Xamarin post on this?

Comment: It was announced by Miguel de Icaza on Twitter, but I don't think that's the official you are looking for.